# .htaccess Regex Watermarking

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, watermark

I have an auto-watermarking script on my website, and the .htaccess file uses this line to redirect all images to the watermark.php file, which watermarks them.  That I all have working, except the .htaccess line also redirects things like .js.  So now my jQuery doesn't work anymore.  The line is this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^thumb].*\.[jJ].*)$ watermark.php?src=$1
```

I didn't write it, I copied it from somewhere.  I think it has to do with the jJ (for .js), but how can I change that to still work with images, but not JS files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above regex matches any file whose extension begins with j or J, and whose filename doesn't consist entirely of `t`'s `h`'s `u`'s `m`'s and `b`'s.  Not exactly what they were going for I don't think.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(?:jpe?g|bmp|gif|png|tiff?))$ watermark.php?src=$1
```

will rewrite anything with the extension:

- jpeg
- jpg
- bmp
- gif
- png
- tiff
- tif

Comment: @dale You are welcome! Glad to know it helped someone else too :)